# wordpress woocommerce form-edit-acount

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I put this code in the funtions.php file, the field is added and even the save_custom_woocommerce_user_fields function is executed, but after the first condition inside this function it is no longer executed.

```
function add_favorite_color_to_edit_account_form() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $custom_img = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'custom_img', true );
    ?>
        <fieldset class="woocommerce-Fieldset info-carts">
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="custom_img"> custom img </label>
                <input type="file" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--upload input-upload" name="custom_img" id="custom_img" accept=".png, .jpg" />
            </p>
            <?php if ( $custom_img ) : ?>
                <p>ok<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $custom_img ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </fieldset>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'add_favorite_color_to_edit_account_form' );

function save_custom_woocommerce_user_fields($user_id) {
    if (isset($_FILES['custom_img']) && !empty($_FILES['custom_img']['name'])) {
        $custom_img = $_FILES['custom_img'];
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $target_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/profile_pictures/';
    
        if (!file_exists($target_dir)) {
            wp_mkdir_p($target_dir);
        }
    
        $file_name = basename($custom_img['name']);
        $target_file = $target_dir . $file_name;
        
        move_uploaded_file($custom_img['tmp_name'], $target_file);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'custom_img', $target_file);
        
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_custom_woocommerce_user_fields');
```

Comment: Note that in your `<input type="file">`, the "accept" attribute value should be `accept="image/png, image/jpeg"`. Now I have tried everything, even a very simplified code version: The variable `$_FILES` is always empty in the function hooked in`woocommerce_edit_account_form` hook, and I really don't catch why.